# Sending mails with multiple attachment in Python

Tags: python, email

I have written a code to send mails with attachment to multiple users using Python. So what this does is, the code will access the csv file, fetch the email address and the corresponding excel file and sends the mail with the attachment.

This code works perfectly fine but the requirement has changed. The new requirement is that, I need to attach multiple files to a single recipient (can't send multiple mails). So for example, I need attach TEST.pdf and another TEST123.pdf file and send to test1@hotmail.com (please refer the image).

I have tried my best but I keep on getting an errors in the code. Can someone help me on this.

**My Python Code**

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import pandas as pd

e = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Hp-Pc\\Desktop\\mail.csv")
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)

server.login("email", "pw")

body = ("""
Hi There

Please refer attachment

Thanks & Regards
""")
subject = ["PDF"]
fromaddr='email'

for index, row in e.iterrows():
print (row["Emails"]+row["PDF"])
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['Subject'] = row["PDF"]
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
filename = row["PDF"]
toaddr = row["Emails"]
attachment = open(row["PDF"], "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)


print("Emails sent successfully")

server.quit()
```

[image: How my csv files looks like with the mail address and the name of the attachment]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **AutoMailer** Application ( made in Python, author : myself )

*It can send multiple attachments. It reads recipients from a CSV file*

( Don't worry, you can easily export your Excel file to CSV, Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel, and Libre Office all support exporting to CSV format )

https://github.com/aahnik/AutoMailer

This is **open-source,** You can see how the feature is implemented. Visit the link above

Answer (score 0):

Please see below.

```
from importlib import reload
import win32com.client as win32
import pythoncom
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd

reload(sys)

pythoncom.CoInitialize()
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

def sendmail(receiver, attachment, subject):
    receiver = receiver
    attachment = attachment
    sub = subject
    body = "Please find the attached supporting documents for member rebates."
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = receiver
    mail.subject = sub.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
    mail.Body = body.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
# Upload multiple attachments/files that meet the conditions/requirements
    for i in range(len(attachment)):
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment[i])
    mail.Send()

# Folder of attachments
path = r"C:\Users\Desktop "

# Address spreadsheet
addr = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Desktop\address.xlsx")

for j in range(len(addr.Code)):
    dirlist = []
# Address spreadsheet includes “Code” which is the recipient’s name/ID, and “add”, the email address
    sub_code = addr.Code[j].astype("str")
    subjects = sub_code + " - invoices"
# If the file names include the recipient’s ID at the start of 4 letters, the file(s) would be added to the list
    for dirpath,dirname,filename in os.walk(path):
        print(addr.Code[j].astype("str"))
        for i in filename:
            if i[0:4] == sub_code:
                dirlist.append(os.path.join(dirpath,i))
    # Send emails to multiple recipients with corresponding attachments            
    sendmail(add r["add"][j], dirlist, subjects)
```

I use this to send every recipient with multiple invoices.